# Using sloccount and grep to get the SLOC after the = symbol

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to automate the process of getting the sloccount for a list of files in a directory and place them into a text file. I need to do this for more than one directory.
The aim is to 'grep' the sloc found after the = symbol

```
Total Physical Source Lines of Code (SLOC)                = 6,392
```

Thus far I have:

```sh
 #!/bin/bash

for file in dir/*; do echo $file;
sloc=`sloccount $file | grep $file`;
echo $file $sloc >> 'activesloc.txt';
done;
```

Or from the terminal I get the output, from using:

```
sloccount ponkout | grep "ponkout"

Creating filelist for ponkout
6392    ponkout      java=6392
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use `cut` to get `6,392` from the line:

```
$ TEXT="Total Physical Source Lines of Code (SLOC)                = 6,392"
$ echo $TEXT | cut -d= -f2
 6,392
```

`-d=` indicates the delimiter is `=` and `-f2` you make the second record to be printed.

Also this `awk` makes it:

```
$ echo $TEXT | awk -F= '{print $2}'
 6,392
```

Comment: how so, if I am doing this for a directory full of files?

Comment: You can also use parameter expansion: `echo ${TEXT#*=}`.

Comment: @james `sloccount`'s `Total Physical Source Lines of Code` line already gives the total number for a directory.